# Como retirar parte do texto de uma string em uma coluna do data frame no r?

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

Olá!

Tenho o seguinte dataframe:

```
Município (Código)                    Município    Valor
2            1100015 Alta Floresta D'Oeste - RO   408765
3            1100023             Ariquemes - RO   477322
4            1100031                Cabixi - RO   126630
5            1100049                Cacoal - RO   463570
6            1100056            Cerejeiras - RO    96654
7            1100064     Colorado do Oeste - RO   266464
```

E preciso que na coluna município seja retirado as UFs, logo preciso que meu dataframe fique assim:

```
Município (Código)               Município       Valor
2            1100015 Alta Floresta D'Oeste      408765
3            1100023             Ariquemes      477322
4            1100031                Cabixi      126630
5            1100049                Cacoal      463570
6            1100056            Cerejeiras       96654
7            1100064     Colorado do Oeste      266464
```

Como faço para obter esse resultado?

Comment: Olá Ingled, confira algumas dicas de como se fazer uma boa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r). Parece que você tem vários objetivos com a sua pergunta. Separe as suas perguntas em tópicos, e coloque o exemplo do data frame que você precisa no final da pergunta

Comment: Olá Ingled, você deve editar a pergunta, e não criar uma nova.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o uso da seguinte expressão regular:

```
gsub("\\s\\-\\s\\S\\S", "", data$Município)
```

Em que `data`é o nome do seu data frame (se você disponibilizar os seus dados através de `dput(head(seu.data.frame, 20))` eu posto a resposta completa.

Na função `gsub`, eu primeiro preciso passar o padrão que estou procurando:

- \\s é a representação de um espaço
- \\- é a representação de um traço
- \\S é a representação de qualquer character não vazio.

Então basicamente ele procura um "espaço"+"traço"+"espaço"+"character"+"character" e troca pelo segundo argumento, que é vazio (""). O 3º argumento é o seu dado.

Exemplo:

```
> gsub("\\s\\-\\s\\S\\S", "", "Ariquemes - RO")
[1] "Ariquemes"
> gsub("\\s\\-\\s\\S\\S", "", "Curitiba - PR")
[1] "Curitiba"
```

Comment: Meu data frame você encontra em : tabela <-get_sidra(api="/t/3939/p/2017/v/all/n6/all/c79/2670"), do pacote sidrar.